# raspbian : How do I both enable built-in wifi and SPI interface for pi3?

Tags: raspbian, spi

The problem is that I need to disable `device tree` to let `SPI` work successfully, but it results in malfunctioning built-in `wifi` and `bluetooth`.

```
uname -a
linux raspberrypi 4.1.19-v7+ #858 SMP Tue Mar 15 15:56:00 GMT 2016 armv71 GNU/Linux
```

This is my /boot/config.txt

```
 hdmi_force_hotplug=1
 dtparam=spi=on
 device_tree=
```

Comment: Are you referring to Pi2 or Pi3? Pi2 doesn't have built-in WiFi and Bluetooth.

Comment: Nobody else has reported needing to disable device tree to get a working SPI.  Why do you?

Comment: sorry, I mean pi3, but pi2 also have the problem.

Comment: someone reported it. https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=97314

Comment: That report is when the move was made to device tree - it says use device tree.  You need to edit your question and include the content of /boot/config.txt so we can see you have correctly enabled SPI etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the line `device_tree=` from /boot/config.txt.  That switches device tree off.

The SPI devices should then be available in `/dev/spi*` and a SPI module should be visible in `lsmod`.